# Same URL on request forward from servlet hence operation repeated again

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

I have been trying to make my project more structured hence i have been following the example  in netbeans ecommerce sample project in https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/page-views-controller.html#controller. I changed my controller according to the example. Now I'm having trouble with going to the page where I display the values in the database.

My Servlet is given below.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    Op_Stock ops = new Op_Stock();
    String userPath = request.getServletPath();
    String param = null;
    Map<String, String> prdMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> lvlMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> stkList = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (userPath) {
        case "/ViewStock":
            stkList = ops.getAllStockDetails();
            request.setAttribute("stkList", stkList);
            userPath = "Stock.jsp";
            param = "type=m&page=stk";
            break;
        case "/AddStockForm":
            prdMap = ops.getAllProducts();
            lvlMap = ops.getAllLevels();
            request.setAttribute("prdMap", prdMap);
            request.setAttribute("lvlMap", lvlMap);
            userPath = "Insertstk.jsp";
            param = "type=m&page=stk";
            break;
        case "/AddStock":
            System.out.println("prdId: " + request.getParameter("prdId"));
            int iprdId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("prdId"));
            int istkIn = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("stkIn"));
            int istkthld = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("stkthld"));
            int ilvlId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("lvlId"));
            int stkIn = ops.insertStockDetails(iprdId, istkIn, istkthld, ilvlId);
            stkList = ops.getAllStockDetails();
            request.setAttribute("stkList", stkList);
            if (stkIn > 0) {
                userPath = "/Stock.jsp";
                param = "message=Stock Details Created!&pg=stk&type=m";
            } else {
                prdMap = ops.getAllProducts();
                lvlMap = ops.getAllLevels();
                request.setAttribute("prdMap", prdMap);
                request.setAttribute("lvlMap", lvlMap);
                userPath = "/Insertstk.jsp";
                param = "message=Could not create!&pg=stk&type=m";
            }
            break;
        case "/DeleteStock":
            int delStk = ops.deleteStockDetails(request.getParameter("stkId"));
            if (delStk > 0) {
                userPath = "Stock.jsp";
                param = "message=Stock Details Deleted!&pg=stk&type=m";
                stkList = ops.getAllStockDetails();
                request.setAttribute("stkList", stkList);
            } else {
                userPath = "Stock.jsp";
                stkList = ops.getAllStockDetails();
                request.setAttribute("stkList", stkList);
                param = "message=Could not delete!&pg=stk&type=m";
            }
            break;
    }

    // use RequestDispatcher to forward request internally
    String url = userPath + "?" + param;
    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    //response.sendRedirect(url);

}
```

In the servlet I'm setting attribute to the request in which the database contents are stored.

Suppose I'm doing an insert operation which is in the switch case "/AddStock" After doing this the request is forwarded to my page where the table is displayed, since i'm using forward it will go to the display page but the URL in the address bar will stay the same with all request parameters from my insert form, hence when I refresh the page the insertion operation will happen again. If I use response.sendRedirect(url), I wont be able to use the request attributes and hence wont't be able to display the DB values.

My Insert form is given below.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
                    <form method="POST" action="AddStock" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">                                    
                                <select id="s_prdname" class="form-control" name="prdId" required>
                                    <option>Select</option>
                                    <c:forEach items="${prdList}" var="mapItem">
                                        <option value="${mapItem.key}">${mapItem.value}</option>
                                    </c:forEach> 
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Level</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">                                    
                                <select id="s_lvlname" class="form-control" name="lvlId" required>
                                    <option>Select</option>
                                    <c:forEach items="${lvlList}" var="mapItem">
                                        <option value="${mapItem.key}">${mapItem.value}</option>
                                    </c:forEach> 
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">In-Stock</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="number" name="stkIn" class="form-control" id="stkIn"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Threshold</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="number" name="stkthld" class="form-control" id="stkthld"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary"><strong>Submit</strong></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

My Display page is given below.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <th><strong>Product Name</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Level</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>In Stock</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Threshold</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Expiry</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Operations</strong></th>
                        </thead>                            
                        <tbody>
                            <jsp:useBean id="lvl" scope="request" class="Level.Level"/>
                            <jsp:useBean id="prd" scope="request" class="Product.Product"/>
                            <c:forEach items="${stkList}" var="row">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><jsp:setProperty name="prd" property="prdId" value="${row.prdStk}"/><jsp:getProperty name="prd" property="prdName"/></td>
                                    <td><jsp:setProperty name="lvl" property="lvlId" value="${row.lvlStk}"/><jsp:getProperty name="lvl" property="lvlName"/></td>
                                    <td>${row.inStk}</td>
                                    <td>${row.thldStk}</td>
                                    <td>${row.expStk}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="deletedata('${row.idStk}');">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                        </button>                                            
                                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                                        </button>                                    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Please help me to solve this problem, if the method I used is wrong please suggest the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I used.

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

Instead of

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
```

And Instead of displaying the values in the DB by setting an attribute in request, I have used   to access the method in my class as shown below.

```
<jsp:useBean id="stk" scope="request" class="Stock.Op_Stock"/>
<c:forEach items="${stk.allStockDetails}" var="row">
    // Values in the map displayed here
</c:forEach>
```